# Not able to connect webflow with github in an automated way. Changes made in webflow should be reflected in github

Tags: github, content-management-system, webflow

I am working on project wherein I need to use webflow along with react components. Now I'm facing an issue while connecting webflow with github. I could not find a proper solution to connect webflow with github in a way such that, whenever a change made in webflow it should be reflected in github.

I could find only a solution by exporting the code manually and use it in github. Need an automated approach to connect webflow with github.